How do I run a single request at the end of a postman collection run
TLDR: Does postman have an equivalent of k6's teardown?
I have a postman collection with two URLs:

https://example.com
https://example2.com

I want to run this collection in Fixed mode with 1 VU for 1 minute. During this minute, requests to https://example.com should be repeatedly sent.
At the very end of the collection run and only once do I want a single request sent to https://example2.com - I will use this to send a cloudevent to notify a tool that my collection has finished.
I've tried adding this to the Pre-request script of https://example2.com but it doesn't work as I'm not specifying a set number of iterations.
if (pm.info.iterationCount != pm.info.iteration) {
    pm.execution.skipRequest()
}


How are you looping the first request?  Do you mean at the end of a performance run? The problem with adding any script that is not directly related to the functionality that you want to performance test is that it will take some time to run and may skew your performance test results.
